# Is there easyest way to change 'resouce' name in web.php [Laravel9]

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm studying Laravel9 routing with sample code and I'm having problem changing URL.
I would like to change URL as below

Currently I can access this URL

127.0.0.01:8000/student/

and

127.0.0.01:8000/student/create

but I would like to change like this

127.0.0.01:8000/fun_student/

and

127.0.0.01:8000/fun_student/create

I wrote like this

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('fun_fun_student')->group(function (){
    Route::resource('students', StudentController::class);   
});
```

but I can't display as this URL.
Could someone teach me correct code please?

UPDATE

I tried

```
Route::resource('fun', StudentController::class);
```

then my current route list

```
  GET|HEAD        fun ............................. fun.index › StudentController@index  
  POST            fun ............................. fun.store › StudentController@store  
  GET|HEAD        fun/create .................... fun.create › StudentController@create  
  GET|HEAD        fun/{fun} ......................... fun.show › StudentController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       fun/{fun} ..................... fun.update › StudentController@update  
  DELETE          fun/{fun} ................... fun.destroy › StudentController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        fun/{fun}/edit .................... fun.edit › StudentController@edit
```

Comment: Laravel8 or Laravel9? Why prefix your routes with `fun_fun_student` when it shouldn't appear anywhere in the url? Have you tried `Route::resource('fun_student', StudentController::class);`? (Check your routes using `php artisan route:list`)

Comment: Dear @brombeer Thank you for answering me. I use Laravel 9  I tried Route::resource('fun_student', StudentController::class); but I got Route [students.create] not defined. error.  so I had been searching a way to change route easily so then I found prefix command.

Comment: The Laravel manual has a section on [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers) along with route names for every action. AND, your route list also shows the route/action names. Use the correct one

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. you mean I have to make each page url one by one ?

Comment: No that's not what I wrote. For `Route::resource('fun', StudentController::class);` the name would be `fun.create` (wherever you use that route, you don't show that)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I need to time to understand what you advice. so could you give me time. I will do my own.

Comment: Dear @brombeer Thank you very much for helping me.
and sorry that I couldn't understand your helping because of my slow brain.I tried Mr.Dasun Tharanga's answer and solved. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the prefix of your resource. you have to change the resource name.

Ex:

```php
Route::resource('fun_student', StudentController::class);
```

Then you can use routes like this:

Ex:

```php
<a href="{{ route('fun_student.index') }}">Students</a>
```

This route should output the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.01:8000/fun_student
```

After the resource changed, remember to clear cache by running:

```
php artisan route:clear
// or
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Also change `route('students.xxx')` to `route('fun_student.xxx')` in other places in your project.

I would suggest you go through the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers) for more information.

Comment: Dear @Dasun Tharanga Thank you for helping me. your answer works really nice. but I stucked at edit page. I post another. Could you take a look this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75991162/after-adjusting-routeresource-in-web-php-happing-missing-parameter-errorlarav

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of Dasun Tharanga, if you are using route model binding, such as:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
*/
public function show(Student $student)
{
   //...
}
```

You have to change the name of the argument to:

```
 public function show(Student $fun_student)
 {
      //...
  }
```

**Or** you have to name resource route parameters

```
Route::resource('fun_student', StudentController::class)->parameters([
    'fun_student' => 'student'
]);
```

Comment: Dear @Khang Tran Thank you for answer.
Looks this really amazing. but sorry this sample CRUD script model are not using binding. but I love this code very much. Thank you.