# After adjusting Route::resource in web.php happing Missing parameter error

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm studying Laravel CRUD routing. Yesterday I post my problem, and many people helped me. In my case, I use Mr.Dasun Tharanga's answer and solved.

[Is there easyest way to change 'resouce' name in web.php [Laravel9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983828/is-there-easyest-way-to-change-resouce-name-in-web-php-laravel9)

It works really nicely, but at edit page I got this error.

> Missing required parameter for [Route: ddd.update] [URI: ddd/{ddd}]
> [Missing parameter: ddd]

When I roll backed as original 'students' it works. I checked controller and model route, but I couldn't figure out the cause. Could someone please teach me how to fix this?

Here is my current web.php

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('ddd', StudentController::class);
```

**edit.blade**

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('ddd.update', $student->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**StudentController.php**

```
 public function edit(Student $student)
{
    return view('edit', compact('student'));
}
```

**LIST**

```
  GET|HEAD        ddd ...................................................................... ddd.index › StudentController@index
  POST            ddd ...................................................................... ddd.store › StudentController@store
  GET|HEAD        ddd/create ............................................................. ddd.create › StudentController@create  
  GET|HEAD        ddd/{ddd} .................................................................. ddd.show › StudentController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       ddd/{ddd} .............................................................. ddd.update › StudentController@update  
  DELETE          ddd/{ddd} ............................................................ ddd.destroy › StudentController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        ddd/{ddd}/edit ............................................................. ddd.edit › StudentController@edit
```

Before I change web.php the working edit page url is like this

http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/5/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my answer in your old question, you can consider to name resource route parameters

in Web.php

```
Route::resource('fun_student', StudentController::class)->parameters([
    'ddd' => 'student'
]);
```

Or you can choose another way that is changing the name of the argument in edit method.

```
public function edit(Student $ddd)
{
    return view('edit', compact('ddd'));
}
```

Remember when you put a model instance as an argument of the controller method, the route segment name has to be the same to the name of argument of the controller method. Reference https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Dear @Khang Tran Thank you very much! I used above answer that you teach me. now Edit page worked fine. Thank you again.